# Passing type-safe route data to routes in angular 2

Tags: typescript, routes, angular2-routing

In my routing module I am passing data in this fashion.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { ShowTopBar: true, showSideBar: false} },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent, data: { ShowTopBar: true, showSideBar: false}}

];
export const AppRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

In order to make the data type safe I have created a `RouteData` class which would hold the `ShowTopBar` and `ShowSideBar` values and initialize them through a constructor.

```
export class RouteData {
constructor(showTopbar: boolean, showSideBar: boolean) {
  this.ShowSideBar = showSideBar;
  this.ShowTopBar = showTopbar;
}
 public ShowTopBar: boolean;
 public ShowSideBar: boolean;
}
```

Now, I have changed the declarations for Routes in the following manner:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: new RouteData(false, false) },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent, data: new RouteData(true, false)}

];
```

which is giving the following error on compiling:

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function
>   'RouteData', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the
>   function or la mbda with a reference to an exported function,
>   resolving symbol AppRoutingModule

My Question is how can we pass `RouteData` in a type-safe way to Routes so that I can take advantage of type-safety.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can do below,

extend Route from `@angular/router` and update Type of data like below,

```
export interface RouteData {
  ShowTopBar: boolean;
  ShowSideBar: boolean;
}

interface CustomRoute extends Route {
  data?: RouteData;
}
```

update type of routes to `CustomRoute[]` from `Routes`

```
const routes: CustomRoute[] = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { ShowSideBar: true, ShowTopBar: true } }
];
```

now you can pass Type safe data, see below,

[image]

Comment: very nice answer thx :) BUT it is important to also read the answer from Eric Liprandi below

Answer (score 17):

Extrapolating on Madhu's answer, if you want your *entire* navigation tree to have those properties, not just the *top* level routes, you must also override the `children` property like this:

```js
interface CustomRoute extends Route {
  data?: RouteData;
  children?: CustomRoute[];
}
```

I had a similar approach to Madhu's but was wondering why my child routes did not have intellisense or type safety. Then I realized the `children` property was still set to `Routes` from the framework's definition.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a small library that covers all typings for the standard router.

[ngx-typed-router](https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-typed-router)

It allows you to have types for everything starting from router configuration, components, resolvers and ending with tests.

E.g.

```
export const ExampleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test/:id',
    component: ExampleComponent,
    resolve: {
      exampleResponse: ExampleResolveService,
    } as ResolveConfig<ExampleTestRouteData>,
  },
];

export interface ExampleTestRouteQuery {
  param1: string;
}

export interface ExampleTestRoutePath {
  id: string;
}

export interface ExampleTestRouteData {
  exampleResponse: ExampleResponse;
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(ActivatedRoute) public route: TypedRoute<ExampleTestRouteData, ExampleTestRoutePath, ExampleTestRouteQuery>,
    // or 
    // @Inject(ActivatedRoute) public route: TypedRoute<ExampleTestRouteData>,
    // all generic types are defaulting to angular standard types
  ) { }

}
```

and template:

```
<div>{{ route.snapshot.data.exampleResponse.id }}</div>
<div>{{ route.snapshot.data.exampleResponse.name }}</div>
```

All is type-safe and refactorable.

Check the documentation for more examples.