# TypeScript/Angular: Adding an interface to data property in router

Tags: angular, typescript

In the *app-routing-module.ts* file, we can use the `data` property to insert our customized fields/variables like so:

```
...
{
  path: 'admin-board',
  loadChildren: './admin-board/admin-board.module#AdminBoardPageModule',
  data: {
    role: 'admin'
  }
},
...
```

My question is that can we add an `interface` inside the `data` property? Something similar to:

```
import { Role } from './role';
...
{
  path: 'admin-board',
  loadChildren: './admin-board/admin-board.module#AdminBoardPageModule',
  data: {
    role: Role = { 
      user: false, 
      admin: true 
    };
  }
},
...
```

It does give the following error:

> 'Role' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
>   here.ts(2693)

The fix that I came up with is removing `Role =` yielding:

```
import { Role } from './role';
...
{
  path: 'admin-board',
  loadChildren: './admin-board/admin-board.module#AdminBoardPageModule',
  data: {
    role: { 
      user: false, 
      admin: true 
    };
  }
},
...
```

but this defeats the whole purpose as I am trying to associate `role` with the interface `Role`.

I should also mention that I have checked the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) of a router and couldn't find anything that helps my situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing type-safe route data to routes in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175065/passing-type-safe-route-data-to-routes-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it, no way - my opinion because data is an Object key/value sperate by ":" and to define a type in TS it's done by the ":' so .....

but what u can do is where u accessed it from a component u can do the following to get the IntelliSense:

```
const role: Role = this.route.snapshot.data['role'] as Role;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.  I'm not certain if it will achieve your goals:

```
import { Role } from './role';
...
{
  path: 'admin-board',
  loadChildren: './admin-board/admin-board.module#AdminBoardPageModule',
  data: {
    role: <Role> { 
      user: false, 
      admin: true 
    };
  }
},
...
```